# Laravel + React: Handling API Data

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm new to react and laravel and I am trying to boost my skills during this god awful lockdown. I'm following tons of tutorials but I keep finding that they are either incomplete, have very bad english or not indepth enough and skip over things too quickly.

I don't mean to sound ungrateful, I love the fact people are sharing this information I am just really struggling to get to grips.

I am hoping someone can help me understand how to make all these components work together. I'll explain my project:

### My Project

- Laravel
- React
- JS Charts
- Bootstrap

I am creating a very basic crypto currency dashboard. That will display a chart and a table of data.

Here is a wireframe:

[image]

I have created the following componenets:

- sidebar
- charts
- table

These are referenced in the `welcome.blade.php` file:

```
return (
        <div className="example">
            <SideBar />
            <Chart />
            <Table />
        </div>
    );
```

I also created a Laraval API that links to my sqlite database. The sidebar displays a list of the crypto currencies I have in the database.

*In the sidebar:*

I am calling the endpoint of `/crypto` I get a returned JSON. This contains a list of all the cryptos in my database (only top 10 at the moment).

```
componentDidMount() {
        
        fetch('/api/crypto')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(crypto => {
                this.setState({ crypto });
            });
      }
```

and then I am adding it to the `state`:

```
constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            crypto: [],
        };
    }
```

Then I am doing rendering that into a list item.

I am doing the same from the `chart` and the `table` however, they only get a specific crypto from the endpoint `/api/crypto?coin=btc`.

All this works fine, the data is shown in the table, the charts show correctly.

### What I want to do.

1. I want to be able to click any of the crypto names in the sidebar, and have the chart and table data update with that specific data.
2. I want to be able to reduce the amount of API calls so that if I do not have to request the database 10 times

I would be extremely grateful for details answers, links and references to videos - tutorials etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I suspect that your `welcome.blade.php` is not where you have your

```
return (
        <div className="example">
            <SideBar />
            <Chart />
            <Table />
        </div>
    );
```

That is usually in a .js file.

What you need to do is something referred to as 'lifting up the state'.

This means that you take the state from your individual components, and move them up to a wrapper component.

In your `App.js` file. It could still be called `Example.js` if you have not changed it. This is where you will see the:

```
return (
        <div className="example">
            <SideBar />
            <Chart />
            <Table />
        </div>
    );
```

Take out all the references for state and the functions in your `sidebar`, `chart`,`table` component.

Add that stuff to the `App.js` file.

Now, when you want to pass info to those components you send them as `props`.

For example:

```
return (
        <div className="example">
            <SideBar tickers={tickers}/>
            <Chart data={data} />
            <Table data={data}/>
        </div>
    );
```

These then become what is known as `Controlled Componenents` and they are stateless. They only rely on the information passed to them.  So when the state changes in `App.js` it will update the lower components.

Check out: https://www.youtube.com/user/programmingwithmosh he is really good and as you mentioned is an issue before, he has great english and very in-depth.

Good luck and well done on using the lockdown for some education and self-betterment.